# Install Different SharePoint Servers using Single Database Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, configuration, sharepoint-2010, microsoft-project

I have a database server in my network running SQL 2008 R2.

I have SharePoint 2010 installed on a separate server and using the above server for database storage.

I want to install a new Project Server 2010 (utilizing SharePoint 2010) on a new 3rd server.

Can I configure the new Project/SharePoint to use the same above database server? Or will it conflict with the previous SP installation? I tried to search the web but I got only issues regarding security and they're not really confirmed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one farm using the same DB server from a technical perspective. I'd be most worried about performance than anything else under those circumstances.

Comment: I would have to agree on your concern regarding performance, but my environment is very small (30 user for SP, 5 for Project). I'm more worried about conflicts within SP if any. Thanks.

Comment: You can manually create the new SharePoint databases for the install to make sure the names are different. I /think/ the SharePoint wizard allows you to add a prefix to your database names as well but I am not 100% certain.

Comment: @top_hat I totally agree with creating the SP databases manually, if only to prevent confusion over which DBs belong to which farm, but IIRC the names it picks are randomised and checked for collisions in the first place anyway.

Comment: It is just the database names that are a potential conflict, so create manually and use a prefix for the second farm for easier management of the databases.